# Jquery remove or change JSON root element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am getting some data back from a third party web service. When the data is returned the root element for the JSON is set to the username of the user. Since this username changes I am trying to find a way to either remove or change this root element. If this can't be done is there a way to modify the lookup of the root element dynamically?

Example returned JSON for one user:

```
{
    "someuseraccount":{
        "data1": 3980203,
        "name": "someuseraccount",
        "data2": 33,
        "data3": 23,
        "data4": 989839
    }
}
```

Example returned JSON for another user:

```
{
    "someuseraccount2":{
        "data1": 3980203,    
        "name": "someuseraccount2",
        "data2": 33,
        "data3": 23,
        "data4": 989839
    }
}
```

When I read the data out into a variable its done through `obj.someuseraccount2.data1`. This causes an issue with the application as it makes it only useable for one user.

Preferably this would be done through Jquery but could also be done through php.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access the data by walking the keys (in this case, there will only be one, but that doesn't really matter).

```
var userData = [];

for (var key in data)
{
   userData.push(data[key]);
   // You don't have to push here, this is only if you want to 
   // add the data to some larger array.
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code, but I am having problems with it. The output I am getting is that each character is being seperated in the array instead of just removing the inner JSON from the root element. Am I doing something wrong?

Example output:

"{", "s", "o", "m", "e", "u", "s", "e", "r" ... etc

Forgive me if I am overseeing something obvious here this is the first time I have encountered JSON in this format. Usually the JSON I deal with does not have the root element

Comment: In this case, 'data' is a string.  I'm not sure how you're getting your JSON into the system, but you may have to make `data=JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Thank you that did it, don't know how I overlooked that. Thanks again!

I would up vote you if I had the reputation btw

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data1,name,data2 etc properties by fetching the first key in the json object then using that key in the json object:

```
function getFirstObjectProperty(obj)
{
    for(var k in obj)
    {
        return k;
    }
    return null;
}

var json = {
    "someuseraccount":{
        "data1": 3980203,
        "name": "someuseraccount",
        "data2": 33,
        "data3": 23,
        "data4": 989839
    }
};
var key = getFirstObjectProperty(json);
var data = json[key];
console.log(data);
```